# How to read number from a console without any variables

Tags: c++, console

I know that for reading from console we can use

```
int number;
cin >> number;
//A line of code where we use int number
```

But is it possible to read a number from console without any variables. Are there any methods that return a number from console?

Comment: If you don't use any variables, where do you plan on keeping and storing the number?

Comment: The most immediate thing I can see using `std::basic_istream` is to use the `get()` method which returns the integer type value of the input character. However, this value wouldn't correspond to the number input by the user, and any input would work, and you'd be limited to practically values between 32 and 126: `int val = 10 + cin.get()` would give you a result of 58 if you entered `0`, for example. This is also still using memory somewhere to store the value, since the result is copied, and not a reference. So I'm going to say no. The canonical way is as you wrote in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But is it possible to read a number from console without any variables.

Read a number without using any variable – sounds like a puzzle.

Here we go:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  return !std::cin.operator>>(*new int());
}
```

This program returns

- 0 … on success (input was a number)
- 1 … on error (input was not a number).

Output:

```
Test 123:
Error: 0
Test abc:
Error: 1
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c57221f4cca22fa)

**Note:**

I somehow had to provide a temporary LValue to the stream input operator.
I had no better idea than `*new int()` though I know this makes a memory leak.
In this simple program, this won't hurt as the OS will make the clean-up for me.

---

> Are there any methods that return a number from console?

This part was really unclear to me.

If I had this problem on my own I would make a helper function

```
int readNum(std::istream &in)
{
  int number; in >> number; return number;
}
```

which I could use then in the `main()` function without any variable

```
int main()
{
  std::cout << "Number: " << readNum(std::cin) << '\n';
}
```

but `readNum()` had again to use a variable to store the result of formatted input.

It's hard to use formatted input stream operators without any variable if the result of input should be accessed again (at least, in C++ with `std` library only).

Answer (score 0):

The getchar() function allows you to ignore one character instead of using a variable to save the value.

Comment: Note that the value of the character is still copied somewhere (at least in a register, just like it would for the multi line example) and this is not a formatted extraction so the resulting single character input would have to be formatted manually.

Comment: I think the author's meaning may just not want to save that value with a variable, such as ignoring a placeholder when reading.